# Using Windows Forms To Upload Arduino Sketch

Tags: c#, arduino, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to make a program that have to upload an Arduino file (.ino) by pressing a button on windows forms.
I looked how to do it and I found that there is a package "ArduinoUploader", but I think I didn't understand how to use it.
It give me this error when I press the button "System.NullReferenceException: 'Reference to an object not set to an object instance.'"
Here is the code that I'm using:

```
using ArduinoUploader;
using ArduinoUploader.Hardware;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    private void SelectProgramButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var uploader = new ArduinoSketchUploader(
        new ArduinoSketchUploaderOptions()
        {
            FileName = @"C:\Users\.....\Desktop\cscharp\.....\.....\TEST.ino",
            PortName = "COM3",
            ArduinoModel = ArduinoModel.Mega2560
        });
        uploader.UploadSketch();
    }
```

Please I need help to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked for the correct Ports (If arduino is already on use with the serial monitor or something like that on that port usually nothing else can access it -> have had issues with saving data to .txt) and for the correct  Arduino model? I've had issues with older arduino boards as they sometimes do not upload the code properly because you have to choose the "upload as legacy" (not 100% sure it is called like that) option so its compatible with older formats.

Comment: The serial port is correct, it is COM3 connected to my Arduino Mega 2560.
I'm using this procedure, but it's not working as well: https://github.com/twinearthsoftware/ArduinoSketchUploader

Comment: I solved the problem, I was not pointing the .hex file, but only the .ino . My bad.